# Do I need to check if the device is connected to the internet to request new interstitial?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have integrated Admob ads in my app and the I working fine, but I don´t know if I can omit the step of checking if the device is connected to the internet to request an interstitial ad.

This is my code:

```
//connectiondetec.java:


public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            //noinspection deprecation
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo anInfo : info)
                if (anInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

        }
        return false;
    }

}

//Activityone.java:

 @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            CallNewInertial();
        }


   private void CallNewInertial() {
        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(Activityone.this);
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            requestNewInterstitial();
        }
    }


 private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(Activityone.this, getString(R.string.interid),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                    }
                });
    }
```

So, could I delete the connection detector class so that now the CallNewInertial is changed to the  following code?

```
   private void CallNewInertial() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
    }
```

updated code to make it work perfect:

```java
 @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        requestNewInterstitial(5);

        }




 private void requestNewInterstitial(int maxRetry) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(Activityone.this, getString(R.string.interid),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {


          if (maxRetry>0){
                         new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                  public void run() {
                 mInterstitialAd = null;
                 requestNewInterstitial(maxRetry-1);
               }
              }, 10000);
                   
                    }
                });
                     }
           
    }




  btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {

                    mInterstitialAd.show(Activityone.this);

                    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                  
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {

                        }

                    });
```

Comment: It would be better to check internet connection before ad requests.

Comment: @ocos is that really neccesary? I have seen that it is working fine not checking internet connection and just call ad requests even if there is no internet connection...

Comment: Whenever there is an error or no internet connection, admob will call `onAdFailedToLoad`. And you are requesting a new ad there. Many requests for nothing. Of course it works 'fine' but just add a log statement to see.

Comment: @ocos mmm I see, a huge number of times the function would be called then... So how do you think I could solve it? Do you think it is a good practice to check for internet connection before or is it possible to make it not checking internet connection in a good way?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a common practice to check the internet connection before loading ad. It's also not very common to reload ad when it failed to load, because usually you start loading a new Interstitial anyway when entering next screen / loading next game level.

However, if your app does not have "natural" points when you request a new ad, then it's fine to reload it in `onAdFailedToLoad`, but limit the attempts to let's say 3 times and optionally add some delay before next attempt.

Comment: I have not understood really way what do you mean about "natural" points. My iterstitial is shown in 2 activities, one of them it is shown when the game level is paused and the also when the game level is finished. In the other activity it is shown when a button is clicked so that when the interstitial is colsed, it moves to another activity, should I reload my interstitial when the ad failed then?

Comment: By the natural point of loading an ad I mean some repetitive initial moment (like starting each game level) so that the ad will be ready later when you want to show it (like the end of level). So, if you start a new Activity for every game level, then just load it in `onCreate` method.

Comment: I have one question, if I check if there is internet connection before loading the interstitial, the onAdFailedToLoad won´t be necessary as the probability that the ad will be shown would be the 100% as there is internet connection, and the only possibility that the ad would not be shown could be that there are no ads at the moment and it wouldn´t make sense to reload the ad, could this be a good practice or it is better don´t checking the internet connection before loading the ad?

Comment: I have edited the details of the question and posted the updated code to make it work perfect now. Do you think it is okay now? I have eliminated to check the internet connection and also I have set a finite number of times to reload the ad in case that it fails, what do you think? Is it fine ?

Comment: Yes, now it's acceptable I would say. The connection detector just adds complexity and has little value.

Comment: when you say acceptable, do you mean that it can be improved? Or it should work like that? I mean, is acceptable bad or good :/

Comment: Your implementation is correct, but I would personally add some delay (maybe 10 seconds) before requesting new add inside `onAdFailedToLoad`. If you would like to do this with `Handler().postDelayed` just don't forget to clear the handler in the Activity `onDestroy` method to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: what would be the Improvements of adding some delay before requesting new add? Also it seems that Handler is deprecated, maybe I could use some alternative method, but, what would be the reason of adding some delay?

Comment: I have seen that using Looper.getMainLooper() is not deprecated. I have updated the code to add some delay as you said, is it looking betetr now?

Comment: after of some days of studying to add the delay I have thought that actually it is not neccesary. A fail to download the add is already a 30 seconds delay. First try + 5 retries it is already 3 minutes of waiting, what would be the reason of adding 50 seconds more? Thanks